# topojson makefile has no country data

Tags: json, d3.js, makefile, topojson

I've been doing the d3 [let's make a map](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) tutorial and I'M SO CLOSE but something happened in merging the two json files because the final uk.json doesn't have the three letter country codes -- rendering my map useless because I can't assign a class to the subunits.

I read [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/l6lnFU2P5-s) from Mike Bostock that said topojson changed and to do this instead when creating the file:

```
  topojson \ 
            --id-property su_a3 \ 
            -p name=NAME \ 
            -p name \ 
            -o topo/uk.json \ 
            topo/subunits.json \ 
            topo/places.json
```

which I ran in the Terminal but same output on the uk.json file. Any ideas? Do I need to make a subfolder within my directory called "topo"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Working code:** Quickly, I find in your code some diferences with mine. Try out this :

```
topojson \ 
    --id-property su_a3 \ 
    -p name=name \ 
    -p name=NAME \ 
    -o topo/uk.json \
    -- topo/subunits.json \ 
    topo/places.json
```

I'haven't test it however. The topo/... path is also a difference with my code.

**2. Missing:** A possibility is that you lost this property upper in your workflow. The GIS file's data attribute name may have changed, etc.

**3. Case sensitive:**  Check that the keys you call in your TOPOJSON match the keys within your GIS / Geojson file. This is case sensitive. To check within the shp file : QuantumGIS* > load the .shp file > Right click on layer > Open attribute table > There, look at the column's title.

*:  or other GIS software

Comment: yeah I used your code and had the same issue... basically my subunits are undefined instead of having the three letter country codes when i make the uk.json file. How do I know if the GIS file's data attribute changed?

Comment: QuantumGIS* > load the .shp file > Right click on layer > Open attribute table

> There, look at the column's title. If I remember well it's case sensitive.

Comment: figured it out -- needed to capitalize --id-property SU_A3 and then it worked! thanks for your help

Comment: Oh. I previously had the same bug for an other variable. My su_a3 works, but I downloaded the data months ago. Note: you can validate & +1 the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, although after a while I realized that the [doc](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference) says

***-p, --properties feature properties to preserve; no name preserves all properties***

So if you use -p without anything else, something like

```
topojson --id-property SU_A3 -p -o yourjson.json -- subunits.json places.json
```

you will get all the features and you will be able to retrieve whatever field you want. I don't know how is that if you only want to map some attributes (I was having the same issue)

Anyway, hope this help